# How to keep a Socket outputstream open and write multiple times

Tags: java, sockets

I am making an application that accepts a TCP Socket connection and displays the info it sends. This works. I have decided though that i want to be able to send information multiple times from the client to the server. Right now this is how it sends.

```
socketStream = socket.getOutputStream();
to_send.add(new String[][] {{
ips + ":" + socket.getPort(),
System.getProperty("user.name"),
System.getProperty("os.name")
}});

sendData(to_send);

while(!finished) {
 socketStream = socket.getOutputStream();
 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream);
 oos.writeObject(new String[][] {{"Open","LOL"}});
 oos.flush();
}
```

-

```
public void sendData(ArrayList<String[][]> d) {
    try {

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream);
        oos.writeObject(d);
        oos.flush();


        System.out.println("Sent: " + to_send.get(0));


    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at Server.<init>(Server.java:57)
    at Server.main(Server.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close the socket in `sendData`.  You will need to handle closing in code outside `sendData`.

EDIT: This exception can be caused when the *remote* side terminates the connection. What is likely happening is that your use of two `ObjectOutputStream`s is causing an exception at the server, which is forcibly terminating the connection.

Comment: That exception is happening in the constructor for class `Server` which you haven't shown (unless it's the anonymous block of code at the top).

Comment: I went to the line '57' at it is pointing here: oos.writeObject(new String[][] {{"Open","LOL"}});

Comment: Yes, it was partly to do with the server, I was also sending a string[][] when i was supposed to be sending ArrayList<String[][]>. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the output stream until you are finished with the Socket. Closing the output stream or the input stream closes the socket.

And don't use multiple `ObjectOutputStreams` and `ObjectInputStreams`. Use one of each, for the life of the socket, at both ends. Otherwise you will run into `StreamCorruptedExceptions`. These things write and expect headers when constructed, and if you open a new one in the middle of a stream the other end will barf.

Comment: Ok i think i did as you said, but now I get an error, see updated post.